Nextjs Error when importing mp4: Module parse failed: Unexpected character ' '
I am currently working on a portfolio, and there were no errors. However, when I imported a video, it gave me this error: 
I've seen other posts talking about this, but everything I tried didn't fix the error.
package.json:
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "framer-motion": "^11.3.8",
    "next": "14.2.5",
    "next-client-cookies": "^1.1.1",
    "next-connect": "^0.12.1",
    "openai": "^4.53.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.40",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-parallax-mouse": "^2.1.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.3",
    "react-scroll": "^1.9.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.7",
    "unsplash-js": "^7.0.19",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.6.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.25.0",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.5"
  },
  "description": "This is a [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) project bootstrapped with [`create-next-app`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/packages/create-next-app).",
  "main": "postcss.config.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/boblamceo/portfolio.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/boblamceo/portfolio/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/boblamceo/portfolio#readme"
}

next.config.json:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    async headers() {
        return [
            {
                // matching all API routes
                source: "/api/:path*",
                headers: [
                    { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
                    {
                        key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                        value: "https://api.limewire.com/api/image/generation",
                    },
                    {
                        key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                        value: "GET,DELETE,PATCH,POST,PUT",
                    },
                    {
                        key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                        value: "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version",
                    },
                ],
            },
        ];
    },
    env: {
        API_KEY: process.env.API_KEY,
    },
};

export default nextConfig;

Import statement:
import AerodynamicVid1 from "../../public/achivements/projects/aerodynamic/A1.mp4";

What is the reason for this error? Is it because I need to do something when importing videos?
